# `R CMD check --as-cran` does not find `diff` on Windows

Tags: r, windows, diff, r-package

I get the following note when checking my package on Windows:

```
> R CMD check --as-cran mypkg_0.1.tar.gz
(...)
* checking differences from 'mypkg-Ex.Rout' to 'mypkg-Ex.Rout.save' ... OK

Message d'avis :
Dans system(paste("diff -bw", shQuote(a), shQuote(b))) : 'diff' not found
(...)
```

Which is not suprising since `diff` is a Unix utility.

How can I check the examples on Windows? (i.e. [step 18 in section 1.3.1 in *Writing R Extensions*](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Checking-packages))

Is there a way without installing `Rtools`? (e.g. defining an alias with `fc`; I tried that without success.) I cannot install `Rtools` due to restrictions from our IT department.

Comment: `diff` is included in `Rtools`.  You should install that, from https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ .

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way without installing `Rtools`? (e.g. defining an alias or anything else) (I edited the question to add more informations.)

Comment: No way, there are many more tools in Rtools. Ultimate solution is simply moving to Linux.

Comment: @user2554330 Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `diff` is included in Rtools. You should install that, from
https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools.

In a comment you asked if you could do this without installing Rtools.   To satisfy the command that triggered the error, you just need any executable program that can be run by calling `diff` from `CMD`.  Best would be an actual `diff` utility, but it doesn't need to actually do anything.

I suspect creating an empty file `diff.bat` would be sufficient, but I haven't tried it.  However, that would mean that you aren't doing the test to compare the two files, so why bother?  There are services online (on Github, at win-builder.r-project.org, on R-hub, etc.) that can do the tests for you.